# PHPExcel : Image is not inserting in excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel

This is my code,
Please tell me what am I missing?

```
    // Field names in the first row
$sql1 = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='user_tab'";
$res1 = mysql_query($sql1);
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
    $fields[] = $row2['COLUMN_NAME'];
}

//Data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tab";
$res = mysql_query($sql);





echo date('H:i:s'), " Load from Excel5 template", EOL;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("mytest.xls");

$logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing();
$logo->setName('Logo');
$logo->setPath('image.jpg'); //Path is OK & tested under PHP
$logo->setHeight(38); //If image is larger/smaller than that, image will be proportionally resized
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($logo, PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);
echo date('H:i:s'), " Add new data to the template", EOL;

$col = 0;
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, 1, $value);
    $col++;
}

$row = 2;
while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $col = 0;
    foreach ($row_data as $key => $value) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
```

Comment: do you see any sign of anything that has been added?

Comment: I can't recall off the top of my head if header/footer images are only supported in Excel2007, but not in Excel5

Comment: Just checked the code; and header/footer images aren't supported in any writer other than Excel2007

Comment: @MarkBaker : so what i have to write for it? "Excel7"?

Comment: You need to use the Excel2007 Writer to create an xlsx file

Comment: How can i use Excel2007?